# concourse fails to put to private docker registry, retrying until 500 error appears

Tags: docker, docker-registry, concourse

I am trying to put a docker image I have assembled in concourse to my private docker registry, ( A registry that I run from docker compose on the host machine which also runs concourse, UI is on 10.250.248.24:8080 ).

**Everytime I get to the put step in concourse, the put fails (500) after an amount of retries.**

Here is an excerpt from the docker-compose file:

```
docker-registry:
  restart: always
  image: registry:2
  ports: ["5000:5000"]
  # environment:
  #  REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE: /keys/docker-registry/docker-registry.crt
  #  REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY: /keys/docker-registry/docker-registry.key
  volumes:
  - /data/docker-registry:/var/lib/registry
```

Here is my resource (docker-registry-maven: 10.250.248.24:5000/maven, docker-registry: 10.250.248.24:5000):

```
- name: maven-image-local
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: {{docker-registry-maven}}
    insecure_registries:
    - {{docker-registry}}
```

Here is the error output:

```
Loaded image ID: sha256:7cf563330eba4a9b5742bf7c294b7e7e1a6930497c2e82553c7a52e63b3db790
The push refers to a repository [10.250.248.24:5000/maven]
1a6063c5c303: Preparing
9531c89475ae: Preparing
ac2f6eda02b1: Preparing
4f1381c6b1c4: Preparing
a78d86126896: Preparing
30125717c842: Preparing
011b303988d2: Preparing
30125717c842: Waiting
011b303988d2: Waiting
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 5 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 5 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 5 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 5 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 5 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 4 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 4 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 4 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 4 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 4 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 3 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 3 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 3 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 3 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 3 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 2 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 2 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 2 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 2 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 2 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 1 second
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 1 second
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 1 second
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 1 second
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 1 second
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 10 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 10 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 10 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 10 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 10 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 9 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 9 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 9 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 9 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 9 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 8 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 8 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 8 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 8 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 8 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 7 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 7 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 7 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 7 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 7 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 6 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 6 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 6 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 6 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 6 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 5 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 5 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 5 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 5 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 5 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 4 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 4 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 4 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 4 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 4 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 3 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 3 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 3 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 3 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 3 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 2 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 2 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 2 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 2 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 2 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 1 second
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 1 second
a78d86126896: Retrying in 1 second
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 1 second
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 1 second
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 15 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 15 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 15 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 15 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 15 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 14 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 14 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 14 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 14 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 14 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 13 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 13 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 13 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 13 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 13 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 12 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 12 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 12 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 12 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 12 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 11 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 11 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 11 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 11 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 11 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 10 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 10 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 10 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 10 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 10 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 9 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 9 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 9 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 9 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 9 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 8 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 8 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 8 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 8 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 8 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 7 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 7 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 7 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 7 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 7 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 6 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 6 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 6 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 6 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 6 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 5 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 5 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 5 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 5 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 5 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 4 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 4 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 4 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 4 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 4 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 3 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 3 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 3 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 3 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 3 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 2 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 2 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 2 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 2 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 2 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 1 second
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 1 second
a78d86126896: Retrying in 1 second
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 1 second
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 1 second
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 20 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 20 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 20 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 20 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 20 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 19 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 19 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 19 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 19 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 19 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 18 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 18 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 18 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 18 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 18 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 17 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 17 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 17 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 17 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 17 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 16 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 16 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 16 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 16 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 16 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 15 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 15 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 15 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 15 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 15 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 14 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 14 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 14 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 14 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 14 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 13 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 13 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 13 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 13 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 13 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 12 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 12 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 12 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 12 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 12 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 11 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 11 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 11 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 11 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 11 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 10 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 10 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 10 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 10 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 10 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 9 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 9 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 9 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 9 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 9 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 8 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 8 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 8 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 8 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 8 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 7 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 7 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 7 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 7 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 7 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 6 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 6 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 6 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 6 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 6 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 5 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 5 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 5 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 5 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 5 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 4 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 4 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 4 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 4 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 4 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 3 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 3 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 3 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 3 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 3 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 2 seconds
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 2 seconds
a78d86126896: Retrying in 2 seconds
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 2 seconds
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 2 seconds
4f1381c6b1c4: Retrying in 1 second
1a6063c5c303: Retrying in 1 second
a78d86126896: Retrying in 1 second
9531c89475ae: Retrying in 1 second
ac2f6eda02b1: Retrying in 1 second
received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error
```

It appears that the container can reach the repo, since from intercept I can:

```
bash-4.3# wget http://10.250.248.24:5000/v2/_catalog
Connecting to 10.250.248.24:5000 (10.250.248.24:5000)
_catalog             100% |******************************************************************|    20   0:00:00 ETA
bash-4.3# cat _catalog                              
{"repositories":[]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  volumes:
 - /data/docker-registry:/var/lib/registry
```

Should be:

```
  volumes:
  - /data/docker-registry:/tmp/registry
```